# Many boxes/atoms never used?

Tags: mpeg4

I'm studying mpeg4 file format according to ISO/IEC 14496 Part 10.But I'm confused that there are many boxes (at least 40) NEVER (in my personal conclusion) be really used,e.g.MPEG-2 transport hint track,ALC/LCT and FLUTE hint track and so on.Could somebody tells me why they aren't be used or how and when to use them?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful ISO/IEC 14496 Part 10 is a video coding standard also called AVC or H.264. The associated file format is ISO/IEC 14496-15 which is based on ISO/IEC 14496-12 (aka ISOBMFF). 
A standard is the result of a compromise between different people, different companies, different application domains and different scenarios. Indeed the ISOBMFF is very wide and many boxes defined in standard may not be used in all scenarios. RTP Hint track related boxes are used only when one goal is to generate RTP packets from an MP4 file. DASH related boxes are meaningful only when you use DASH. Of course a single file may have multiple purposes and so some boxes may not be processed by some tools.

Comment: Thanks very much,this confuses me for a long time.But the result seems that it is not easy to find that kind of .mp4 file.Thanks!